# Applying Chebychev's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I am trying to figure out how to apply Chebychev's inequality on this example: Suppose $\bar{X}$ is the mean of $n=100$ observations from a population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 9$. What are the limits in which $\bar{X} - \mu$ will lie with probability of at least $0.90$.

I know Chebyshev's inequality is
$$P[g(Y) \ge r] \le \frac{\mathrm{E}[g(Y)]}{r}$$

I think $r$ can be $0.90$ in this case, so I would have
$$P[(\bar{X} - \mu) \ge 0.90]$$

I am not sure if I am on the right track, and I am unsure how to apply this inequality. What should I do from here?

Comment: You are seeing answers that look different from your inequality because there are two things commonly called "Chebyshev's inequality": the one you quoted (which is also known as Markov's inequality) and the one you get by applying Markov's inequality with $g(Y) = (Y-E[Y])^2$, giving the variance on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tchebychev's inequality is
$$ \mathbb{P}(|Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]|\geqslant\varepsilon)\leqslant\frac{\mathbb{V}[Y]}{\varepsilon^2} $$
Since $\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}]=\mu$, we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(|\overline{X}-\mu|\geqslant\varepsilon)\leqslant\frac{\sigma^2}{n\varepsilon^2} $$
But $\frac{\sigma^2}{n\varepsilon^2}\leqslant 0.10\iff\varepsilon\geqslant\sqrt{\frac{0.10}{n}}\sigma$. With such a $\varepsilon$, you have
$$ \mathbb{P}(|\overline{X}-\mu|<\varepsilon)\geqslant 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{n\varepsilon^2}\geqslant 0.90 $$

Answer (score 1):

$\bar{X}$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$. Chebychev's inequality implies
$$P(|\bar{X}-\mu| \ge t) \le \frac{\sigma^2/n}{t^2}.$$
Set the right-hand side to $0.1$ and solve for $t$ to obtain the interval $[\mu - t, \mu + t]$.